# How to simplify this loop (DataFrame in pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hey I have a DataFrame in which values of a column `Values` are lists, where each list contain a strings with 3 characters. For a `values` from `values_list` I want to replace last character by "I" in each list in `Values` column. That is my current code:

```
for i in range(len(data["Values"])):
    for k in range(len(data.iloc[i]["Values"])):
        if data.iloc[i]["Values"][k] in values_list:
            data.iloc[i]["Values"][k] = data.iloc[i]["Values"][k][:2] + "I"
```

How can I rewrite it in more proper way?

Comment: can you give the header of your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really clear on what you are trying to do, but I think this is what you mean.

You can define the function and then use `.map()` on that column:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'Values':[['aaa','bbb','ccc'],
                               ['ddd','eee','fff']]})


print(data)

values_list = ['aaa', 'ccc', 'eee']

def subI(value_list):
    value_list = [x[:-1] + 'I' if x in values_list else x for x in value_list]
    return value_list

data['Values'] = data['Values'].map(subI)

print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
print(data)
            Values
0  [aaa, bbb, ccc]
1  [ddd, eee, fff]
            Values
0  [aaI, bbb, ccI]
1  [ddd, eeI, fff]
```